# PIL Images are not garbage collected

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I have a random image picker, and images created by PIL are not garbage collected, even if I delete `self.rand_img.image`. I can collect it by destroying `self.rand_img`, but it's very inconvenient. It's there any other way, how to solve this?

Here's my code.

```
import os
import random
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk

class App:

def __init__(self):

    def load_imgs(path=str()):

        for i in os.listdir(self.path + path):

            if i.endswith((".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png")): self.pics.append(path + i)
            elif os.path.isdir(self.path + path + i): load_imgs(path + i + "\\")

    self.w = None
    self.h = None
    self.pics = []
    self.path = input() + "\\"
    self.root = tk.Tk()
    self.root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    load_imgs()

    print(len(self.pics))

    self.rand_img = tk.Label(self.root, bg="red")
    self.rand_img.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nwse")
    self.rand_img.update()
    self.new_img()

    self.btn = tk.Button(self.root, text="Next", command=self.new_img)
    self.root.bind("<Return>", self.new_img)
    self.btn.grid(row=1, column=0)

    self.root.mainloop()

def new_img(self, event=None):

    def resize(event=None, img=None):

        w = img.size[0]
        h = img.size[1]

        self.rand_img.update()

        if w > h:
            
            master = w / self.rand_img.winfo_width()
            w = self.rand_img.winfo_width()
            h /= master

        elif h > w:
            
            master = h / self.rand_img.winfo_height()
            h = self.rand_img.winfo_height()
            w /= master

        if w > self.rand_img.winfo_width():

            master = w / self.rand_img.winfo_width()
            w = self.rand_img.winfo_width()
            h /= master

        elif h > self.rand_img.winfo_height():

            master = h / self.rand_img.winfo_height()
            h = self.rand_img.winfo_height()
            w /= master

        if self.w != w or self.h != h:
        
            img = img.resize((int(w), int(h)))
            img_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
            self.rand_img.configure(image=img_tk)
            self.rand_img.image = img_tk
            print(self.rand_img.image)

        self.w = w
        self.h = h

    img = Image.open(self.path + self.pics[random.randint(0, len(self.pics))])
    resize(img=img)

    self.rand_img.bind("<Configure>", lambda event: resize(event, img=img))


app = App()
```

Comment: What are you trying to acheive?

Comment: How do you know that the image is not garbage collected?

Comment: Because my RAM is after around 100 images bloated.